# Inner product of two Schwartz fucntions.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, inner-products, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Say I have two Schwartz fucntions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Does $\int f(x)g(x)dx \approx 0$ imply that $f(x)$ $g(x)$ have virtually non-overlapping support ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: As in your other question, there is not much work from you, don't you think ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, just take $f$ even and $g$ odd.

Comment: Ah I see, it was this simple. Thank you.